# Pattern of the question paper

Tags: phd, mathematics, exams, india, qualifying-exam

To pursue a Ph.D. in Mathematics in India, one must clear the central entrance exams (written) like [CSIR-NET](https://csirhrdg.res.in/Home/Index/1/InPage/38/26), [GATE](https://gate.iitk.ac.in/doc/Syllabus/ma.pdf), [NBHM](https://www.imsc.res.in/%7Enbhm/qp/) or institute specific exams such as ISI, CMI, TIFR first. After that, the students are eligible for an interview for the Ph.D. position.

In almost all the exams, the questions of different topics are jumbled up together. However, I believe if the questions are categorized (all questions of algebra at one place, all questions of analysis at one place, etc.), it is easier for students to score better. ([Example](https://www.imsc.res.in/%7Enbhm/qp/nbhmra22.pdf) of type 1 exam, [Example](https://www.imsc.res.in/%7Enbhm/qp/nbhmra19.pdf) of type 2 exam).

What is the philosophy behind setting a paper where the questions of all topics are mixed up? Is it just made this way to make it more difficult for the candidate to ace the exams or anything else?

Comment: You can always do the algebra questions first, then the analysis questions next, then linear algebra, .... Is there ant rule that says you must start from the first question, then the second one, sequentially?

Comment: @Nobody There is no rule, but it would be nice to have all at one place!

Comment: "However, I believe if the questions are categorized (all questions of algebra at one place, all questions of analysis at one place, etc.), it is easier for students to score better". You believe based on what?
 
The philosophy may as well be to help candidates, so they immediately realize that if one question is difficult or of a difficult (to the candidate's feeling) they do not get paralyzed and stuck by fear of failing. Vote to close

Comment: Asking after "the philosophy" behind a particular test format seems ill-suited for the Academia.SE format. Who can say other than the people who create the test? Perhaps if you changed the question to ask for whether this particular test format has been studied and any results, it wouldn't be opinion-based. It may then be out of scope, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Personally I think the question is OK. People may have experience in or know literature about the construction of such tests. It's a valid concern and I can imagine useful answers to be given, even though I don't have one.